# Does anyone know how to open a JSR-82 application in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, mobile, bluetooth, jsr, jsr82

I have a host device that connects to anything running JSR-82. The problem is that I don't have a mobile device that runs JSR-82 applications. I wish I could simply connect to my host device within windows. Is this possible?

(I am currently running Vista x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what protocol the host device is speaking, you could write your own client using regular desktop Java and the [Bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) implementation of JSR-82.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried for example using phone emulator from [Nokia's SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Tools/Java_Tools.xhtml)?

Comment: I tried... but I can't seem to get these to install in Vista x64

Answer (score 0):

Considering even the latest Java Platform Micro Edition Software Development Kit 3.0 doesn't officially support Vista x64 (http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp#req) I can only advise using a different operating system.

Sorry.